# Blazor Hybrid ElementReferenceJsonConverter throw an exception only when debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, blazor

Followed the setup steps from Microsoft, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/walkthroughs/build-first-hybrid-app

Set the Android Emulator to start

[image: Selected Android Emulator version]

Load it up with the debugger and I get this error

[image: Exception thrown]

If I stop debugging and load up the app in the emulator, it works fine

[image: working app]

Anyone else had this and know how to fix it? The error only appears while debugging. On first load it does show the index page very briefly before erroring.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by updating the `System.Net.Http.Json` (in the shared project) and `System.Text.Encodings.Web` (in the Android project) to 6.0.0. In the initial template, they are still supporting 3.X.X versions.